# how to disable dropdown(?) on Google Maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm using Ruby on Rails and don't have much knowledge in JavaScript(of course, my overall coding is so poor). I customized Google Maps API and wanted to make infowindow. However when I made my infowindow, 'sometimes' dropdown popped up in desktop(not in cell phone).

I think it's not only the Google Maps problem. I assumed that it can be any HTML, CSS related problem but no idea afterall..... It's very strange because dropdown only pops up when the restaurant's name is some kinds(two words or name with some number, but I can't recognize what is the exact cause and difference..)

```
# my_javascript.js

function googleMap() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var restAddr = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var restName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': restAddr}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var restLatLng = results[0].geometry.location

      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: restLatLng
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: restLatLng
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          //maxWidth: 100, it didn't work
          content: restName // **this part is the problem. When the restName is like "new york", "house 2"(some with one-digit(?)-number). but not when the restName is "new york stree" kind. **
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
window.onload = googleMap
```

and this is my view file.

```
# app/views/home/page.html.erb

<%= @rest.addr %>
<p>changed</p>

<input type="hidden" id="address" value="<%= @rest.addr %>">
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="<%= @rest.name %>">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Can anyone help me with some suggestions? Any comments will be very helpful to me and make me learn more about programming. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the infowindow content in da DIV and style the div with css.
In your case do `'<div class="scrollFix">'+restName+'</div>'` und set the div properties to:

```
.scrollFix {
    line-height: 1.35;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

here is an working example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/veaz/7Zm8w/

Comment: Thank you @Manuel!! I couldn't think of styling right into that infowindow contents. It was a good lesson to me and your reference made me understand more easily. Thanks!